# Sending data with token does not work (POST request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I send a data with Post request, but error is displayed for me (this line code : `console.log(e);`
I gave the ‍‍`token` manually to test the code
It works for me in the postman, but the code below doesn't work for me:

```
  const sendDataTab1 = async (e) => {
    const token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL"
    try {
      const api = `/api/v1/test/add`
      await axios.post(api,{ headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} });
      console.log("hihihi");
    } catch (e) {
      toast.error(e.response.data.error, { autoClose: 15000 });
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please add more information on what's happening ? _doesn't work for me_ is not very helpful. What are you trying to accomplish, what is happening that should not, what is not happening that should, etc. In doubt, please refer to the [ask] section.

Comment: Also, it is not advice to post sensitive information in stackoverflow questions. You should replace your token with a generic placeholder, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you post via axios, second param is the data, and third param is the config (https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

Therefore you are sending your headers as POST data.
Maybe try:

```
await axios.post(api,{}, { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} });
```